# git rev-list exclude from branches matching pattern

Tags: git

I want to write a query to git rev-log to do something like

```
git rev-list HEAD ^origin/a ^origin/b ...
```

where I exclude all the commits reachable from branches on origin.

I see that there is the `--branches=origin/*` flag I can pass, but I don't seem to be able to combine it with the `^` option to exclude them.

The ultimate goal is the find the closest commit to HEAD that exists on a remote branch. I was looking at `git merge-base`, but that doesn't quite work here I think.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the correct way to do this is by using `--not` instead of ^.

```
git rev-list HEAD --not --branches=origin/*
```